# Create event handler where showUI is true, and after some time its false

Tags: lua

I am creating a Restart Server message, that will be displayed on client side, im stuck on this, and looping around, but cant find any solution. I tried this code block below, but cant seem to find a solution within. Could someone help me with this :D

```
        RegisterNetEvent('notif')
        AddEventHandler('notif', function()
            SendNUIMessage({
                action = 'notifRestart',
                showUI = true; 
            })
            Citizen.Wait(10000)
            SendNUIMessage({
                action = 'notifRestart',    
                showUI = false; 
            })
            print("bik")
        end)
```

```
        window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
            data = event.data;
            console.log(data);
            if(data.action == 'notifRestart'){
                console.log(data.showUI)
                if(data.showUI = false){
                    console.log(data.showUI)
                    $('.restart-wrapp').css('display', 'none');
                }
            }
            
            // if (item.showUI) {
            //     $('.notif').show();
            // } else {
            //     $('.notif').hide();
            // }
        });
```

```
        Citizen.CreateThread(function()
            while true do
                Wait(1000)
                local currTime = os.date("*t")
                print(trenutnov)
                if currTime.hour == 10 and currTime.min == 11 then
                    TriggerClientEvent('notif', -1)
                    print("[RESTART] - Send Notif")
                    break
                end
            end
        end)

        RegisterCommand('sas', function()
            TriggerClientEvent('notif', -1)
        end)
```